# Docker volumes занимает много места на диске

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

Я новичок в Docker. Использую OC Ubuntu Server 20.04. Недавно я заметил, что мой контейнер mysql постепенно потребляет все больше памяти на диске. То есть директория /var/lib/docker/volumes/mysql/_data через несколько дней работы контейнера становится 60 GB и выше.

Сама база данных небольшая (около 1.5 ГБ). В чем может быть причина такого большого потребления памяти и как от этого можно избавиться?

Единственное решение, которое я нашел сейчас, это просто удаление данной директории и перезапуск службы docker.

На скриншоте ниже видно сколько места стал занимать volumes спустя пару дней

UPD: Исследовав директорию _data я заметил, что у меня множество файлов binlog.*** размером от 1 до 2 Гб.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой docker-compose.yml с mysql:

```
    mysql:
    image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
    command:
        - --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
        MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
        MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
    volumes:
        - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
    networks:
        - sail
    healthcheck:
        test: [ "CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}" ]
        retries: 3
        timeout: 5s
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может быть связана с тем, что в контейнере mysql включен механизм автоматического создания бэкапов, который сохраняет копии базы данных в директорию /var/lib/mysql/backups. Эта директория может занимать много места на диске, особенно если база данных обновляется часто.

Чтобы решить проблему, можно отключить механизм автоматического создания бэкапов, добавив следующую строку в файл docker-compose.yml:

```
environment:
    MYSQLDUMP_DATABASE: "false"
```

Также можно удалить старые бэкапы вручную, используя команду:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/volumes/mysql/_data/backups/*
```

Если эти меры не помогут, можно попробовать уменьшить размер логов mysql, добавив в файл my.cnf (который находится в директории /var/lib/mysql) следующие строки:

```
log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log
log-bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days=7
max_binlog_size=100M
```

Это уменьшит размер логов и может помочь снизить потребление памяти на диске.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, я проверил и у меня нет бекапов. Я обновил свой вопрос, есть ли у Вас еще варианты которые могут мне помочь?

Comment: @Vanya228 , Тогда можно попробовать Ограничить размер логов и бинлогов в конфигурационном файле MySQL. Для этого нужно добавить в файл my.cnf (обычно он находится в директории /etc/mysql) следующие строки:


[mysqld]
max_binlog_size=100M
expire_logs_days=10

(Вы можете поменять на свои числа)

Первая строка ограничит размер бинлогов до 100 МБ, а вторая удалит бинлоги старше 10 дней.